# Call two functions on events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I´m trying to call two functions when closing the jQuery UI Datepicker, but I´m not sure what´s the best way to do this.

If I only have one function I can do this:

```
function splitArrivalDate() {
    // Some code
} 

$( '#mydatepicker' ).datepicker({
    onClose: splitArrivalDate
});
```

But what if I want to call two functions sequentially on the onClose event?

```
function splitArrivalDate() {
    // Some code
} 

function setDepartureDate() {             
    // Some code
} 

$( '#mydatepicker' ).datepicker({
    onClose: splitArrivalDate; setDepartureDate // Does not work
});
```

I hope someone can help me understand this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
$( '#mydatepicker' ).datepicker({
    onClose: function () { splitArrivalDate(); setDepartureDate(); }
});
```